Machine learning approach for bot detection
I am working on a project that tries to determine if users are bots or not. Currently, the labels that the dataset contains are not reliable, but I have found some trends/features that are solid for determining bot behavior.
My question is the following: How should I approach this dataset with bad labels? I have a couple of ideas but I am not experienced enough to know which one is best.

Use the features(which are a small subset of the total features) that I observed to relabel data using a weighted sum approach. Then, use the relabeled dataset in a supervised ml algorithm

Use an unsupervised ml algorithm

Can I use both to compliment each other?


I have researched on this topic already but it seems like there are a lot of differing opinions

How do you know these trends/features are good at determining bot behavior? How do you know the labels are not reliable?

@user2974951 The labels are not reliable because they are simple and only consider a user in isolation, not how a user might be related to other users. I have manually looked through a lot of data and have found a lot of examples proving the scores aren't foolproof. As for my features, they are nearly impossible to exhibit without being a bot. An example of one of them is if a user logins next the same user above an arbitrarily high amount of times. Yes, this could happen in theory, but for the amount of users in total, it is really improbable
